# Add value to all integers in a list

Tags: list, kotlin, iteration

I have a list of integers:

```
val mylist = listOf(1,2,3)
```

How do I create a new list on the fly such that the values in this list are now 4, 5, 6? I can't find a suitable list function that does this.

eg

```
val newlist = ListUtils.union(mylist[x], mylist[x].addintegervaluetoeverythinginlist)
```

In Python, list iteration makes this simple with: `(i+3 for i in list)`, not sure what to do in Kotlin, though.

Comment: `myList.map { it + 3 }`? You can do this with any sequence, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe said in the comment already, [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) is the right function for this - it's not defined on just `Sequence`, but also on `Iterable`, which `List` is:

```
val newList = listOf(1, 2, 3).map { it + 3 }
```